# Download all images listed in database using PHP

Tags: php

We are currently in the process of restructuring our CDN Server and store assets in relevant folders.

Our previous developer stored all images and documents under one folder referenced by image names in the database.

> Storage path: //cdn.example.com/i/

Table example

```
-----------------------------------------------
id | first_name | last_name | gender | image
-----------------------------------------------
1  | John       | Jackson   | 1      | 1973507_302350463306528_o.png
```

Now what i want to do is store all images related to people in a 'person' folder in the cdn and so forth. is there a way i can download all people related images from the database into a folder - or perhaps using a curl?

Comment: Why do you have to download them, and not just move them.  Besides what code have you tried.  Anything is possible.

Comment: try  file_put_contents()

Comment: Our new cdn is on a new server. i want to download from the old server and upload to the new one.  - no code tried yet. i wanted to find out if it was possible to accomplish it

Comment: I think the best way of doing this is, write a php code in the back end. The code will read the database and based on that the the images will move to respective folder. So, if you have multiple type of folder then move those images as per your need. No need to write crul for that. If you know that there is no more data insert then, make a php file and run in your browser.

Comment: Cool. thanx for that